# WxPython PropertyGrid Show the Time

Tags: wxpython

I found this to show date on property grid:

```
pg.Append( wxpg.DateProperty("Date",value=wx.DateTime.Now()) )
```

[image]

How can i show the time instead ?
Something like HH:MM:SS with a scroller.
Thanks